# Clipping converts multiband to single band

Tags: qgis, saga

I have a multiband raster image. I am trying to extract the AOI by using "Clip raster with polygon" option in SAGA module. The process clips the raster to the exact size of the polygon but the resulting image is in single band and not in multiband as the input. There is no other option in "Clip raster" in SAGA other than input layer and polygon layer. I am using QGIS 3.4.

EDIT:

I tried the option **clip raster by mask layer** already. I am getting a black rectangle as an output. I used the default setting with **match the extent of clipped raster to mask layer extent** checked. Both the input and mask layer is having the same CRS.

Answer (score 2):

Recent SAGA GUI (including the latest version 7.3) has tools to work on multiband rasters, called `Grid Collection` in SAGA, but most SAGA tools are designed to handle single band rasters.

**Clip Grid with Polygon** in SAGA GUI, which is equivalent to **Clip raster with polygon** in the QGIS Processing Toolbox, will break the multiband raster into a set of single band rasters before clipping (masking) them by the designated polygon. Unfortunately SAGA 2.3.2 under the QGIS Processing Toolbox uses only the first band among them.

Instead, please try QGIS (or GDAL) tool: **Clip Raster by Mask Layer** (from the menu  `Raster > Extraction`).
It will take the multiband raster  and automatically outputs new multiband raster masked by the given polygon.

Answer (score 0):

Try batch processing in Clip raster with polygon tool in QGIS. You have to make several rows in batch processing, according to the number of your bands. After finishing you will get clipped image for individual bands. If you need to combine all the bands together again, you can do composite of all the bands.